# vsftpd won't start with ssl_enable=YES. Why or where can I find logs about why?

Tags: debian, ssl, ftp, vsftpd

I just configured vsftpd but if try enable ssl in the config file, my server doesn't start.  In other word, vsftpd won't start with `ssl_enable=YES`

What can I do about this? I thought there should some information in the log files, but I can't find this information in `/var/log/vsftpd.log`

How can I find out wheres the problem located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you specified a certificate file in your vsftpd.conf? i.e. rsa_cert_file=/path/to/vsftpd.pem

Comment: Yeah, specified but it didn't exists, that was the problem thanks.